# Is it possible to calculate a GRU RNN in its entirety by hand on a small dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, rnn, data-science-model

I want to see whether my code works and compare it to the results I do myself

Comment: Hi @J_Bake, welcome to the site. If you want to compute something by hand, you can just do it. The only thing preventing you from doing that would be not wanting to spend the required time. What is exactly the question?

Comment: How can I get an example of the maths to compute it?like a paper or something

Comment: For the formulas, you can resort to the [GRU wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit).

Comment: Yes but is there someone who did it by hand and showed the process calculation by calculation.

Comment: Not that I am aware of